# Array RenderFlex Overflowed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

**Problem :**

I want to show List data in Text Widget. but its OverFlowing remaining array I want to show in next line.

**Image :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
 Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.timer_rounded, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Text(
                                    '${timeslot[index]}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: detailsize, color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                  ),
                                ],
                          ),
```

**What I Tried :**

If i use Expanded or Flexible its showing nothing . Image is down below.
[image]

**Full Code :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HistoryPage> createState() => _HistoryPageState();
}

class _HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final currentuser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  late User? _currentUser;
  bool isLoading = true;
  List<dynamic> gameList = [];
  List<dynamic> timeslot = [];
  List<String> collection = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    print("Current Email : ${_currentUser!.email!}");
    fetchData(_currentUser!.email!); // Use current user's email ID
  }

  // Function to fetch data from Firestore based on the current user's email ID
  Future<void> fetchData(String emailId) async {
    await fetchCollectionData('CommanZone', emailId);
    await fetchCollectionData('PrivateZone', emailId);
    await fetchCollectionData('GameStation', emailId);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  // Function to fetch data from a specific collection based on user's email ID
  Future<void> fetchCollectionData(String collectionName, String emailId) async {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore
        .collection(collectionName)
        .where('Email', isEqualTo: emailId)
        .get();

    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
      if (data != null) {


        List<dynamic> zoneIdList = data['ZoneId'];
        List<String> zoneIdStrings = zoneIdList.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
        List<dynamic> zoneIdIntegers = zoneIdStrings.map((e) => int.parse(e)).toList();


        gameList.add(zoneIdIntegers);
        print('gameList : ${gameList}');
        // for (var sublist in zoneIdList) {
        //   if (sublist is List<int>) {
        //     gameList.addAll(sublist);
        //   }
        // }

        List<dynamic> timeIdList = data['TimeSlot'];
        List<String> timeIdStrings = timeIdList.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
        timeslot.add(timeIdStrings);


        collection.add(collectionName);


      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.055;
    final double detailsize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.050;
    final double iconhead = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07;

    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(
        child: Lottie.asset('animation/amongusloading.json',
          height: 300,
          repeat: true,
          fit: BoxFit.cover
        ),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: gameList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 15,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.gamepad,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,size: iconhead,),
                              SizedBox(width: 5,),
                              Text('${collection[index]}',
                                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: size,color: Colors.black)),
                            ],
                          ),

                          Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.timer_rounded, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                                SizedBox(width: 5),
                                Text('${timeslot[index]}',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: detailsize, color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),

                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.computer_rounded,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                              SizedBox(width: 5,),
                              Text('${gameList[index]}',
                                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: detailsize,color: Colors.grey.shade700),maxLines:3,),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above code is of HistoryPage. Im trying to show users bookings by their EmailId. And trying to show their bookings.

In Listview.Builder i have created Card which is showing (CollectionName,timeslot,ZoneId) .
This is code where im getting problems i hope you will try to help me.

Comment: Please put a full necessary code for solution. Thanks

Comment: My answer updated according to your question updated please look into this and mark this question as Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your text inside [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget

```
Row(
  children: [
    const Icon(Icons.timer_rounded, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
    const SizedBox(width: 5),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        'Put Your Extra large text here hope this time its working if its not then please let me know I will help you in your problem.',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          color: Colors.grey.shade700,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

#### Updated Answer using Row:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 15,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.gamepad,
                        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Common Zone',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.timer_rounded,
                        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Put Your Extra large text here hope this time its working if its not then please let me know I will help you in your problem.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.computer_rounded,
                        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        '[1,2]',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

#### Using ListTile -

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 15,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  visualDensity:
                      VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                  leading:
                      Icon(Icons.gamepad, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                  title: Text(
                    'Common Zone',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  visualDensity:
                      VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.timer_rounded,
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                  title: Text(
                    'Put Your Extra large text here hope this time its working if its not then please let me know I will help you in your problem.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  visualDensity:
                      VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.computer_rounded,
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                  title: Text(
                    '[1,2]',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Result using Listtile - [image]

Result- [image]

Result using Row- [image]

Comment: Then its not showing the text , Area is showing blank.

Comment: I updated my problem with Expanded and Flexible kindly check out.

Comment: Sir , i updated my question with full code.

Comment: ListTile worked  , thank you for you efforts and time

Comment: @FenilTrivedi Happy to help you Enjoy your ride with Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text widget with a flexible widget

```dart
Row(
 children: [
Icon(Icons.timer_rounded, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
  SizedBox(width: 5),
Flexible(                               
child : Text('${timeslot[index]}',
 style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: detailsize, color: Colors.grey.shade700),
    )                              ),
]
)
```

Comment: Its not showing the Text, showing nothing,

Comment: I updated my problem with Expanded and Flexible kindly check out.

Comment: Please post the full code. Its the row wrapped with any other widget

Comment: sir , I added full code with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i created a sample basic code depend on your defined screenshot and here the my code. And i replicate your issue. And solve using below code please match or relate your container code too..

**Output of my code:**

[image]

**Here the code:**

```
 return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: const Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 15,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.gamepad,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Text('sdf'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.timer_rounded,
                                    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                                SizedBox(width: 5),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    '[9:00 Am-09:30 AM,9:00 Am-09:30 AM,9:00 Am-09:30 AM,9:00 Am-09:30 AM,9:00 Am-09:30 AM,9:00 Am-09:30 AM,]',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.computer_rounded,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'asdasd',
                                maxLines: 3,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Its still not working , you can check out my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your text in SizedBox like this

```
        Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.add),
            Expanded(child: SizedBox(child: Text('...')))
          ],
        )
```

Comment: No its not working , you can check out question i updated the question.

Comment: when i do this my text going to next line 
Can you tell me more about your problem?

Comment: timeslot is list of String its not "Text" , which im trying to show in Card if i use Expanded time is not visible as shown in question. thats what i can say ☹️.

Comment: you put that on SizedBox ?

Comment: Yes i tried , no change

Comment: I did no change, showing blank as shown in question.

Comment: When I'm not using SizedBox it's empty but if I'm using SizedBox it's showing
I don't know where your problem comes from

Comment: in my case its vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should wrap `Row` to `Flexible` or `Expanded`. Try this code.

```
                                Flexible(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    const Icon(Icons.timer_rounded, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      'Put Your Extra large text here hope this time its working if its not then please let me know I will help you in your problem.',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
```

If it will not work then Please try to wrap text as well with `Flexible` or `Expanded`.